# Preferences bundle -- iPhone vs. Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I have a preferences bundle that exhibits different behavior in the simulator vs the phone.  The basic problem is that the default values of my preferences are getting read fine on the simulator but are coming up NULL on the iPhone.  Is there some kind of special initialization I have to do for the device in order for these to be seen there?

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: You do not need to do any special initialization. Please post your code that is setting up your references as well as the code that is reading/writing to preferences.

Comment: There's nothing special do to with device vs. simulator.  You might have the values cached in the simulator somehow.  Reset the simulator and do a clean build from Xcode and you'll probably end up with the same problem on the simulator.  If you haven't figured out the problem yet, let us see how you're setting the defaults.

Comment: I ended up re-arranging the code so that I didn't need a preferences bundle. (Was only using it in development anyway).  I'm pretty sure that the values probably were cached in the simulator though because I saw something similar happen in other cases.  I solved that by removing the app from the simulator and re-launching it.